# Coloring \underbracket?

Tags: formatting

Can I color just the `\underbracket` in text or presentation, without coloring the entire text and subtext contained in it?

Because `{\color{red} \underbracket{Some text}_{Some other text}}` will color everything, and I don't need that.

Comment: You mean the underbracket symbol, not either of the two 'texts'?

Comment: Yeah, I only want that to be red, not the texts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`\color{red}{\underbracket{\color{green}{5}}_{\color{blue}{6}}`

Remove/replace the other color  specifications as you wish.

The first `\color{red}{\underbracket{...}}` statement acts on the symbol itself, not on the following texts.

Comment: This did the trick, I have to manually add `\color{black}` in other  text

Comment: @dingo_d: That's fine

Comment: You should put `\color{red}` inside the folowing group so that the red color doesn't affect folowing text: `{\color{red}\underbracket…}`.